How to setup ediff-merge-files to interactively either save the mergebuffer or abort the merging when calling from the command line
I want to merge the two files $FILE1 and $FILE2 via emacs(client) into a $FILE3 on the command line with a way to abort the merge.
I tried
emacsclient --eval '(ediff-merge-files "'$FILE1'" "'$FILE2'" nil "'$FILE3'")'

but I have two problems:

Exiting is complicated: I get asked

Quit this Ediff session? (y or n) y
Merge buffer saved.  Now kill the buffer? (y or n) n


Despite all these questions there is no way to exit the merge without saving! If I answer Quit this Ediff session? quit with "no" I stay in the Ediff system. And my answer to the second question (Now kill the buffer?) doesn't make a difference. $FILE3 always is written out.


The real bummer is here point 2. How can I setup ediff-merge-files (or another ediff function) to interactively either save the merge buffer or abort the merging?

IIUC, you want to interactively merge two files, resolving conflicts manually, then  quit the merge without confirmation (IOW, assume that you always type y to the Quit this Ediff session? prompt)  and then have a dialogue with the system about saving the merged buffer: sometimes you want to say y, sometimes n: if y, the function has to save the merged buffer to the given file and exit; if n, the function has to just exit, throwing away the merged buffer. Is my understanding correct?

Yes, that's it - That's what I'd expect from a (manual) merge tool. Open the two files in buffers, do the merging in the buffers with teh help of diffing and then finally decide during the exiting of the merge function to save the merge to the result file or not.

So you have use the two-argument form of ediff-merge-files that does not automatically save the buffer and deal with the saving of the buffer yourself. As for the Quit question, you can override y-or-n-p using cl-flet. Untested, and I'm unlikely to be able to test it and/or provide a solution any time soon.

@NickD You say to "deal with the saving of the buffer yourself". BUt that is super cumbersome! Is there no way to tell Ediff to abort without saving the merge buffer or "commit" by saving the meregbuffer to the appropriate file? -- Will update the question to make this clearer.

No:  if you call ediff-merge-files  with four arguments, then you are implicitly saying that you want to save the buffer. Saving a buffer to a file is bread-and-butter stuff for Emacs: you do it all the time and there is nothing cumbersome about it (at least I think so: I have not tried to write it).

I tried a simple-minded implementation as described above and failed utterly. I don't really understand how ediff-merge-files works, but it seems to be more complicated than I thought. It's not so much the saving-the-merged-buffer part: that is easy. But turning off the y-or-n question and the control flow in ediff-merge-files are giving me indigestion ATM.
